# Floating Divs are on top of each other

Tags: html, css, floating, stacked

I'm working on a screen that I'm trying to make somewhat responsive. By this I mean that if the screen size changes, the divs should move to the next line.

It's a little something like this:

```css
.contributor_thumbnail {

    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #777;

}
```

```html
 <div class="contributor_thumbnail">thumb here</div>
   <div class="contributor_thumbnail">thumb here</div>
   <div class="contributor_thumbnail" style="height:2px; width:48px;">thumb here</div>
   <div class="contributor_thumbnail">thumb here</div>
```

There are 4 divs side by side. One of them is a little smaller than the rest.
Depending on the size of the screen, the last div will place itself over the second last one. You might need to inspect the divs and change the width of contributor_thumbnail until you get this result (as seen in attached image)[image]

Is there anyway to have a floating divs not stack on top of each other. I know I could set display: inline-block; to all but that is not an option for me.

Comment: You should try flexbox instead.

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/5bh49qpd/

Comment: flexbox on the body seems to do the trick. Thanks for the help :)